# Jenkins running multiple xcode jobs with simulator?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, ios-simulator

My configuration has Jenkins master(ubuntu) + slave(Mac Mini)

I would like to run multiple build tasks (4 workers, for example) with unit testing at the same time. The problem is that it can be only one xcode simulator running, so all jobs except first hang and cannot finish.

Is it possible to run several simulators or at least wait for other simulator (not the whole job) to finish?

I found this [project](https://github.com/plu/parallel_ios_tests), but it allows only different devices, for example iPhone 5 and 6.

Comment: Xcode 9 now supports multiple simulators. `xcodebuild test` can also run tests concurrently if you specify multiple destinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to wait for simulator availability by adding these commands in build step (execute shell)

```
make install_ci

while [ "$((`ps aux | grep iPhoneSimulator | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l`))" -ne "0" ]; do
sleep 10
done
make test
```